# Drupal 8 Hide Title If Front Page

Tags: 8, theming

In drupal 8 how can I hide title on front page ? The title is rendered through page-title.html.twig through the code below

```
{% if title %}
  <h1{{ title_attributes.addClass('page-header') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

I want to wrap it in **if not front page** condition but don't know the syntax.

Comment: Try with {% if is_front %}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use the is_front variable

```
{% if not is_front %}your code{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 8):

The title is displayed in a block. Go to the block layout (/admin/structure/block), look for the block "Page Title", click on "Configure" and set the visibility on "Pages" to hide for `<front>`:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I didn't noticed that. Thanks for the answer, I must be using this option.